# How to investigate more about some .so file giving Sytem error:exec format error in AIX

Tags: c, oracle, aix, oracle-golden-gate

I have created a shared library of a C program. I created the .so file using `-Xlinker -G` option. This library will be called from Oracle Goldengate(userexit).But when oracle tries to load the module,it abends stating "System error:exec format error".
Is there any way I can investigate more about what's going wrong while loading the library?

Comment: output of `file libyourname.so` is?  Possible that your lib is 64bit and theirs is 32, or vice versa, among other things.

Comment: the output is :  executable (RISC System/6000) or object module not stripped . Oracle Goldengate version 12c so it's 64 bit for sure. I don't know about mine

Comment: @JohnH: hey,you suggestion worked.Turned out my gcc compilation was resulting in a 32 bit library.I compiled a 64 bit version and everything starts working fine.Please post your suggestion as answer so that I can mark the question as solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the output of `file libyourname.so`...

In my experience, it it possible that your lib is 32bit and theirs is 64bit, or vice versa, among other things.

A 32-bit module will show:

```
   libname.so: executable (RISC System/6000) or object module not stripped
```

A 64-bit module will show:

```
   libname.so: 64-bit XCOFF executable or object module not stripped
```

Answer (score 1):

When you compile an application on a server which may not be at exactly the same OS version as the one you wish to run it on, you may see the following error:

cannot load .... : Exec format error

Here are some things to check:

1) Make sure your libraries are at the right versions and levels (especially libc):

## dump -H /path/to/executable

2) If you had asynchronous I/O configured on the compilation server, enable it on the new server as well:

## lsattr -El aio0

Check to ensure autoconfig is set to "available" if it is enabled.

If you need to able aio:

## mkdev -l aio0

## chdev -l aio0 -a autoconfig='available'

Note: Oracle executables need of Asynchronous I/O to work properly.
Example

dump -H /path/to/executable; mkdev -l aio0; chdev -l aio0 -a autoconfig='available'

Also,you can refer below link:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21253974

Comment: I have already check all this but unfortunately it did not help. :(